# Optimizing for loop inside for loop django: added link

Tags: django, for-loop

I have a function which checks for a profile name and determines if it is in a tagged profile name.

```
def check_profiles(request):
    try:
        # get all individual profiles
        profiles = Profile.objects.all()
        # get all individual tagged profiles
        tagged_profiles = TaggedProfiles.objects.all()
        # ids to exclude in adding dates
        exclude_profiles = []
        # for profile in profiles
        for profile in profiles:
            # for tagged in sdn list
            for tagged_profile in tagged_profiles:
                # if contains 1
                if any(name in tagged_profile.name_breakdown() for name in profile.name_breakdown()):
                    # put in exclude
                    exclude_profiles.append(profile.pk)
                    profile.status = 'FOR REVIEW'
                    profile.save()
                    break
        

        for profile in Profile.objects.all().exclude(pk__in = exclude_profiles):
                cleared_dates = profile.cleared_dates
                cleared_dates.append(
                    {
                        'date': datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
                        'time': datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
                    })
                logger.debug(cleared_dates)

                profile.cleared_dates = cleared_dates
                profile.save()
            
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(e)
```

Basically, if a `profile`'s name is `'firstname lastname'`, it's breakdown is `['firstname', 'lastname']`. And if `tagged_profiles` include either a `'firstname'` or a `'lastname'` in any of it's breakdowns, it's a hit.

But I'm doing it very inefficiently. How may I optimize it with any of django's built in functions?

You can see it [here](https://www.online-python.com/NxH6svWAOJ).

Comment: Can you share your models?

Comment: @Mekicha I have a sample code that does the same. Its this https://www.online-python.com/NxH6svWAOJ